# Problem with shell script sequence commands

Tags: shell, sh

I'm new on shell script and I don't know how to achieve that.

I need to log as an user ( a user with a .bashrc config that put me on a directory when login ) and after, run some commands as this user at this directory.

my script below stops on login and run the rest only if I logout from user.

```
su play
play stop
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
play start
tail -f logs/system.out
```

Edit 1: I record a video to help understanding

https://www.loom.com/share/a0e64c6835ba485187cf073389e1bbb8?sid=2cbedcbf-eabd-4455-a74f-75bae4cd6638

Comment: `tail -f` will keep trying to display new information from the file. See if removing the `-f` resolves your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks for reply my friend. The problem is when i run the script, the execution stops after "su play". When i quit from play user, the script runs the rest of command below

Comment: When you do a `su play`, you get an interactive shell, i.e. one which expects some input. You need to feed something into this shell. If the shell requests the input via stdin, you could try to use input redirection. However, in case you run into time issues with this approach (i.e. that new input is only accepted once the old one has been consumed, and therefore input is lost), you need a tool which can drive interactions. The most common one is [expect](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Expect), which means that you have to program the interaction in the programming language Tcl.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307067/how-to-execute-sudo-commands-with-expect-send-commands-in-bash-script)  helps you to get you going. While this website specifically mentions _bash_  as a shell, I don't tee anything in it which you couldn't do in _sh_ either.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved with some workaround based on my scenario.

here the full script that works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/play/play-1.7.1/cashup-starter
../play stop
git config --global --add safe.directory /home/play/play-1.7.1/cashup-starter
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
../play start
```

Thanks to everyone that help me to reach the solution